# fscaret VarImp$matrixVarImp.MSE returns 0

Tags: f#, caret

I'm trying to use the fscaret package on ordinal data (predictors) and an ordinal response, the data is from a survey on a scale interval from 1-10.

I have managed to get my script work , however sometimes depending on the data frame I feed into my script when calling VarImp$matrixVarImp.MSE , it returns 0. I have tried to figure out why but am not capable to find the root cause.
all_data is the dataframe in MISO format. I have not attached the data due to confideniallity...

Here is my  simple script:

```
library(fscaret)

set.seed(1234)
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(all_data$response, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- all_data[ splitIndex,]
testDF  <- all_data[-splitIndex,]


fsModels <- c("glmnet","pls", "nnet")


start.time <- Sys.time()


myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE,
              Used.funcRegPred = fsModels, with.labels=TRUE,
              supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)

end.time <- Sys.time()

total.time <- end.time - start.time
```

output matrix

```
myFS$VarImp$matrixVarImp.MSE

myFirstRES$VarImp$matrixVarImp.MSE
   gbm glmnet lm nnet pcr pls SUM SUM% ImpGrad Input_no
1    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN       0        1
2    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        2
3    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        3
4    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        4
5    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        5
6    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        6
7    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        7
8    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        8
9    0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN        9
10   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       10
11   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       11
12   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       12
13   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       13
14   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       14
15   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       15
16   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       16
17   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       17
18   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       18
19   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       19
20   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       20
21   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       21
22   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       22
23   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       23
24   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       24
25   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       25
26   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       26
27   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       27
28   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       28
29   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       29
30   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       30
31   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       31
32   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       32
33   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       33
34   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       34
35   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       35
36   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       36
37   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       37
38   0      0  0    0   0   0   0  NaN     NaN       38
```

any ideas?

Here is my actual data set :
I have dropped the na to clean the data up before running fscaret...

```
> str(all_data)
'data.frame':   7288 obs. of  39 variables:
 $ v1      : int  9 8 7 9 10 9 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v3      : int  9 8 9 10 8 8 10 10 8 9 ...
 $ v4      : int  9 8 8 9 8 8 10 10 8 9 ...
 $ v5      : int  8 8 7 10 8 7 10 5 10 10 ...
 $ v6      : int  8 8 8 9 9 9 10 5 10 8 ...
 $ v7      : int  8 8 7 8 9 8 10 5 10 8 ...
 $ v8      : int  9 8 8 10 10 9 10 5 10 9 ...
 $ v9      : int  9 8 8 7 8 6 8 8 10 5 ...
 $ v10     : int  9 7 7 9 5 7 10 6 10 7 ...
 $ v11     : int  8 8 6 9 5 9 10 8 10 7 ...
 $ v12     : int  8 9 6 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v13     : int  8 9 7 9 8 8 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v14     : int  9 10 8 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v15     : int  10 8 8 10 10 7 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v16     : int  9 7 7 10 9 9 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v17     : int  9 10 7 10 5 7 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v18     : int  8 8 6 10 10 7 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v19     : int  9 9 8 9 10 9 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v20     : int  8 8 8 9 6 8 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v21     : int  8 8 8 10 5 7 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v22     : int  8 8 7 9 5 8 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v23     : int  8 8 6 10 5 8 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v24     : int  9 9 8 9 9 9 10 7 10 10 ...
 $ v25     : int  9 10 7 9 8 9 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v26     : int  9 8 7 7 8 9 10 9 10 9 ...
 $ v27     : int  8 8 7 9 9 9 10 9 10 9 ...
 $ v28     : int  8 8 7 9 8 8 10 9 10 6 ...
 $ v29     : int  9 9 8 9 8 8 10 9 10 8 ...
 $ v30     : int  9 9 7 7 8 8 10 8 10 8 ...
 $ v31     : int  9 10 6 9 9 9 10 7 10 8 ...
 $ v32     : int  8 8 7 9 9 7 10 8 10 5 ...
 $ v33     : int  8 10 8 9 8 8 10 7 10 8 ...
 $ v34     : int  8 6 8 10 9 9 10 9 10 8 ...
 $ v35     : int  9 8 8 9 10 7 10 9 10 8 ...
 $ v36     : int  9 10 9 10 10 9 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ v37     : int  9 8 8 10 10 9 10 5 10 10 ...
 $ v38     : int  9 10 8 10 10 8 10 10 10 8 ...
 $ v39     : int  8 10 8 9 10 9 10 9 10 8 ...
 $ response: int  10 7 8 9 9 8 10 10 10 10 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:3307] 12 13 15 17 32 34 35 40 41 42 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3307] "12" "13" "15" "17" ...
```

###update

tried to down sample the df, then I got this error message:

```
Error in if (abs(x[i, j]) > cutoff) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: It is a good idea if you are posting a sample script that it avoids any unneeded details as well as being compilable/runnable on its own.

Comment: Be glad to, any ideas of how to do that?

Comment: So start by getting rid of everything that is not required (at least all the time related stuff) and add definitions for what is missing.  More in depth guide here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: tried to dput the data , was to large though.. any ideas of how to get the data in...

Comment: dput(head(all_data,2))

Comment: Does it repeatedly fail for one particular data frame? Could you perhaps try dropping some of the rows from the data frame until you have something very small and then replace the actual numbers with some dummy numbers? (It might be something specific about the data - like containing `NaN` or `NA` values - but that's hard to say without having a reproducible example...)

Comment: I have updated with a str(), for the real dataframe. It should be clean, only containing integers from 1-10.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code with some changes:

```
myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=FALSE,
              Used.funcClassPred = fsModels, with.labels=TRUE,
              supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)
```

Use Used.funcClassPred instead of Used.funcRegPred.
Secondly preprocessData is used to remove predictors will high correlation therefore using preProcessData for nominal data doesnt make sense.